# Why is the jquery method html() still have old content when using val() to update input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   <div id="test-node">
         <input id="input-test" type="text" name="" value="old old old">
   </div
```

……

```
$("#input-test").val("new new new");
console.log($("#input-test").html());
```

The console log is `<input id="input-test" type="text" name="" value="old old old">`

Why does `val()` not update the input vallue? When I use `attr()`, it does work well.

Comment: Side note: After changing using `val()` , if you'll fetch using `prop()`  you'll get the current value.

Comment: @philantrovert `val()` is also a getter

Comment: @charlietfl just trying to confuse him even more.

Comment: @philantrovert huh? That is the most common way in jquery of getting a form control value. Just saying use `prop()` without showing how is even more confusing

Comment: @philantrovert haha~ The most confusing place is Property and Attribute distinction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method will just update the `value` property of the element and not the `value` attribute.

To get the current value use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method without any argument.

```
$("#input-test").val("new new new");
// to get the value use the val() method
console.log($("#input-test").val());
```

```js
$("#input-test").val("new new new");
console.log($("#input-test").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test-node">
  <input id="input-test" type="text" name="" value="old old old">
</div>
```

---

To reflect in HTML code update the attribute using [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

```
$("#input-test").attr('value', "new new new");
console.log($("#itest-node").html());
```

```js
$("#input-test").attr('value', "new new new");
console.log($("#input-test")[0].outerHTML);
console.log($("#test-node").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test-node">
  <input id="input-test" type="text" name="" value="old old old">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#input-test").val("new new new");`

This line of code updates the **value** of the `input`, not change the element itself. Since you execute this function, you will notice on the browser screen that `input` will have a value `new new new`

If you want to change to `value` attribute of the `input` element, you should do something like:

`$("#input-test input").attr("value", "new new new");`

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because the ***value attribute*** and the ***value property*** of an element are not the same once any user input or programmatic changes are made

The value attribute is only used by browser to be able to set the value property if applicable.

Try using `val()` as getter:

```
$("#input-test").val("new new new");
console.log($("#input-test").val());
```